# What modifies the speed of fans?

Tags: electric-machine

I remember the maximum speed that my ceiling fan could offer me on a sunny day when it was new.But after 2-3 years of usage the maximum speed that my fan offers have reduced a lot.Even when the regulator is at its full the speed of the fan is horrible.so my question is:

Which part of my fan needs to be replaced so that it offers me the same speed as it used to?

Comment: So uh, are we supposed to guess what kind of fan you're talking about? Is this a desk fan, PC cooling fan, USB fan, or perhaps a fan of your band?

Comment: @bort it a ceiling fan sir.

Comment: Depends on the design of that particular fan, do you have a schematic?

Comment: @old_timer it's a normal household ceiling fan.no specific schematic.

Comment: lesser-known than wear but very common is a relatively-large capacitor inside the ceiling fan drying out and needing replaced. The smoking gun is loss of power and not much diff between levels. These are square parts the size of a matchbox and can be replaced for $5-$20. You have to replace exactly, but [here's one example](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/like/122233607465?chn=ps&chn=ps)

Comment: I don't know about ceiling fans but for desktop/floor fans it is quite common to have the bushings dry up and need a bit a of oil to run well again. Of course as others have pointed out it could also be a faulty run capacitor.

Comment: @scanner that is the point, no reason to assume any two fans used the same design, and thus any two fans have the same fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes open them up and clean them... Also check condition of the bushes, as I am sure they may have used bushes instead of bearings for cheap construction / possibly to deliberately wear. If so they are probably a standard size and you should hopefully be able to swap them out. If they are bushes I would suggest bearings as replacement as they might even give you higher speeds and better efficiency than standard :)

.

(P.S. Assuming an AC motor here?)

Comment: Yeah it's a ac motor.

Comment: Cool, well then hopefully a good clean and checking the bushings should sort them out. Nearly all household fans I have dealt with use bushes not bearings - which turns them into throw away items very quickly under heavy use. 

De-mucking will free them up, the bushes are often copper or brass, so soft metal, ebay or similar should help you source some bearings of suitable dimensions - take pics at each stage of deconstruction and then it should be easy to reassemble :)

Comment: P.S. - if the bearing is correct diameter but not depth and you cant fit two in, then you can use suitably sized washers on the internal diameter to pad them out!

Answer (score 1):

### Clean it

There is little chance the slowing down was caused by electronical wear. Dust, on the other hand, can slow it down *a lot*

So i recommend you take it apart carefully (take pictures!) and clean/grease the moving parts.

Comment: Cleaning didn't help i had tried it a lot of time.The fan that i am talking remains in use for most of the time and its speed is low.while the fan in the adjacent room which use is limited gives pacifying speed .I wanted to ask if some internal parts needs to be changed.